# Can we ask for dialect identification questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a particular question in mind, which may be somewhat opinion-based and thus off-topic here. My question is on the pronuncation of "Catholicism". I've heard it pronounced by emphasizing on the first syllable, even though online pronunciation guides say it's pronounced on the second syllable. Now, you may think "Well, it must be idiosyncratic then!" No, I don't think it's that person's idiosyncrasy, because this artist tends to [pronounce that way too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXsZbkt0yqo). I believe, for this reason, that the unusual pronunciation is really a dialect, and I need help in identifying this dialect.

Comment: Are you asking the question "Can I ask this?" or actually asking about the dialect? Currently, it seems this post falls between the two stools: but the first belongs here, and the other belongs on the main site.

Comment: This is not about the meta question, but it seems quite clear that the artist says Catholicism with the emphasis on the first syllable to match the meter of the Lady Gaga song.  It didnt sound like a dialect to me. Additionally [Amy Burvall](http://www.amyburvall.com/#!about/c1se) (the singer of the song) is a teacher in Hawaii.

Comment: What @paqogomez said. The same "artist" enunciates an exaggerated ***Cath-ER-ine** [the Great]* on [another Lady Gaga "cover"](https://www.thisismyjam.com/song/amy-burvall-re-mixes-lady-gaga/catherine-the-great-a-re-mix-of-poker-face), where it's obviously primarily for the sake of the musical meter. The chances of there being a "dialect" where stress falls on the first syllable of ***Catholicism*** seem negligible to me.

Answer (score 4):

Dialect questions are a bit haphazard, but we have answered them before. If you post your two examples and possibly more, and feel you can identify other common dialectal features, you have a good shot of being on topic. However, it's difficult to identify a dialect from a single word. Maybe you could compare the backgrounds of those two people and discover a common dialect and have your answer that way.